# DB2 encrypt field in select statement

Tags: db2

So I need to do a select statement, while encrypting a field in SHA2_512. I'm not sure which DB2 version it is, but I tried both queries and neither work.

When trying this query:

```
SELECT HEX(HASH_SHA256('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRZTUVWXYZ'))
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

I get the following error:

> Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884,
> SQLERRMC=FUNCTION;HASH_SHA256, DRIVER=3.71.22 SQLState:  42884
> ErrorCode: -440 Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501,
> SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=3.71.22 SQLState:  26501 ErrorCode:
> -514

While with this query

```
SELECT hash('Charlie at IBM', 3)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMYU;
```

> Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884,
> SQLERRMC=FUNCTION;HASH, DRIVER=3.71.22 SQLState:  42884 ErrorCode:
> -440 Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=3.71.22 SQLState:  26501 ErrorCode:
> -514

(while without the hash functions the query runs without any issues). Anyone know how I can fix this issue?

I'm not sure which DB2 version I'm using but by using these queries I get these results:

```
  SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

> DSN11015

```
select  GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.NEWFUN')  AS COMPATIBILITY from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

> **COMPATIBILITY**: V11

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=functions-hash

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=sf-hash-crc32-hash-md5-hash-sha1-hash-sha256

Comment: To be honest I do not know. Is there a way within DB2 I can check this?

Comment: The query does not work. When looking in some documentation I think it is z/OS, but cannot tell more. The person that I can ask is currently OOO..

Comment: This gives me 'DSN11015'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233621/discussion-between-sofboy-and-mao).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using Db2-v11 for Z/OS  "DSN11015" in V11 compatibility mode.

This version lacks the scalar function [HASH_SHA256 (and others)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=sf-hash-crc32-hash-md5-hash-sha1-hash-sha256) which is present in Db2-v12 for z/OS.  That is the reason you get sqlcode -440  (no such function HASH...) with your Db2-for-z/os version.

At Version-11 , IBM documents a function [ENCRYPT_TDES](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-encrypt-tdes) which may help you.

[Background information on using this function.](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=functions-defining-encrypt-tdes-function-value-level-encryption)

You can write your own functions if you have the skills.